# Using .htaccess to make fancy URLs with a wide variety of characters

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm wanting to make a URL look pleasing to the eye.

```
from 
    /index.php?a=grapes
to
    /grapes
```

Although, I'm having a few problems. I wanted `a` to have a wider variety of characters like `a-z A-Z 0-9 / _ - . [ ]`.

```
from
    /index.php?a=Grapes.Are.Green/Red[W4t3r-M3l0n_B1G_Gr4p3]
to
    /Grapes.Are.Green/Red[W4t3r-M3l0n_B1G_Gr4p3]
```

In the index.php file I have

```
<?php
    $a = $_GET["a"];
    echo $a;
?>
```

just to test the URL is working correctly.

Right now what I have in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9/_]+)?$ index.php?a=$1
```

only accepts `a-z A-Z 0-9 / _`.

- If I add `-` into the square brackets and have it as one of the
  characters which `a` equals I get the 404 error.
- If I add `.` into the square brackets I get `index.php` outputted.
- If I add `[` or `]` I get the 404 error.

If anyone has a solution I'd love to see it. Also, if anyone has time please could you explain each part of the RewriteRule saying what the part does. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried something like `^(.*)$` (untested, may be a bit off) that accepts all characters?  Is there something that would make you not want to accept all characters?

Comment: @jedwards - If I use `^(.*)$` I get `index.php` outputted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?a=$1 [QSA]
```

The `[QSA]` thing at the end is what made it work :) Thanks to jedwards for suggesting to use `^(.*)$` which accepts all characters.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that some of your character are "special":

Special characters:

```
(full stop) - match any character
* (asterix) - match zero or more of the previous symbol
+ (plus) - match one or more of the previous symbol
? (question) - match zero or one of the previous symbol
\? (backslash-something) - match special characters
^ (caret) - match the start of a string
$ (dollar) - match the end of a string
[set] - match any one of the symbols inside the square braces.
(pattern) - grouping, remember what the pattern matched as a special variable
```

So if you want to use them in a url, you have to scape them.

For example
    .s?html? matches ".htm", ".shtm", ".html" or ".shtml"

Comment: I just read a little about it, I have used a .htacces just a time

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm now using `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9/_\-\[\]]+)?$ index.php?a=$1` which allows `- [ ]` extra. How can I add '.' to the set? I've tried backslashing it but, again, I get `index.php` outputted.